# How to change config item value by calling a codeigniter controller function?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a controller function that attempt to change a config item but it doesn't work. How can I change the value of a config item by calling this controller function? Here are my codes:

maintenance_config.php

```
<?php  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

 //Maintenance mode

 $config['maintenance_mode'] = FALSE;
```

controller file function

```
function maintenance_mode_activate(){

 $this->config->load('maintenance_config');
 $this->config->set_item('maintenance_mode', TRUE);

}
```

Comment: You want to change it temporarly or permanently..??

Comment: I want it temporarily. It seems like I will click a button to activate maintenance mode then click another button or the same button to deactivate the mode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the comments on your question, you want to store the fact that you website is in *maintenance mode*.

The code that you've posted does indeed change the config value, but only for the duration of the request/processing thread in PHP - to refer to your example, once the flow that involves running the maitenance_mode_active() method is executed, the configuration option is lost.

The set_item() method does not overwrite a setting in your file, it simply changes the value **in memory**. You can circumvent this in two ways:

### 1. Store the value in a database.

Simply create a table to store configuration options for your application, and then create a row that has an example value of *maintenance-mode* set to 0. Once you press the button, change it to 1 and simply retrieve that value whenever you need it.

### 2. Store it in a PHP file that can be overwritten.

This method, although not as clean, has the advantage that you can keep using the $this->config property to manage your code. Basically, when you press the *maintenance-mode* button, write the following content to a file (for example purposes, let's call it prop.php):

```
<?php

$config['maintenance-mode'] = true;
```

Now you simply need to include it in your *config.php* file:

```
include_once("prop.php");
```

You now can reference the configuration option via $this->config. If you want to set maintenance mode off, simply overwrite the file with:

```
<?php

$config['maintenance-mode'] = false;
```

Let me know if that's the functionality you were looking for!